# vba to copy to different ranges

Tags: vba, excel

I have this sheet called `Consulta` where everytime I change the value on the column K it changes the color of the range E:K to green or white if it's empty.

I also want to if the row is green, copy that row to the sheet called `E-mail`. This is what I've tried so far and it works:

```
Sub ChangeColor()
Dim ws As Worksheet, ws1 As Worksheet, i As Long, lastrow As Long

Set ws = Sheets("Consulta")
Set ws1 = Sheets("E-mail")

lastrow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row


For i = 5 To lastrow
If ws.Range("K" & i) <> "" Then
    ws.Range("E" & i & ":K" & i).Interior.ColorIndex = 43
    ws.Range("E" & i & ":K" & i).Copy ws1.Range("A" & i & ":G" & i)
Else
    ws.Range("E" & i & ":K" & i).Interior.ColorIndex = 2
End If
Next

If ws.Range("E" & i & ":K" & i).Interior.ColorIndex = 2 Then
    ws1.Range("A" & i & ":G" & i).Clear
End If
End Sub
```

My problem is with this line below:

```
ws.Range("E" & i & ":K" & i).Copy ws1.Range("A" & i & ":G" & i)
```

I actually want to copy to a different range instead of the corresponding range in the sheet `E-mail` (for example, if the first match is E3:K3 I want to copy to A2:K2. If the second match is E34:K34 I want to copy it to A3:K3 and so it goes).

I tried using another loop but my Excel got crazy so I think I did it wrong.

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only need the upper-left corner cell for a destination. Look from the bottom up for the last used cell and offset down a row.

```
with ws1
    ws.Range("E" & i & ":K" & i).Copy .cells(.rows.count, "A").end(xlup).offset(1, 0)
end with
```

You might want to put this above the line that applies a fill color or you will be copying the fill color as well.

Comment: That's it! Thanks a lot, I've totally forgot `Offset`. And you're right about the color.

Comment: I realize that this just messed up my `Clear` when the color is withe but I'll try to fix that.